# in winforms, can i drag a control with a bunch of controls (like listboxes) in it into another control and resize / move them from there?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm running into some situations where it has been nice to make a control (Control A) with a bunch of things in it like buttons, listboxes, datagridviews etc so I can drag it into other controls (Control B) whenever I like, so I don't have to write the logic for the stuff within Control A over and over again.

The only annoying thing with this approach has been that I can't seem to find a way in the designer to move/resize the buttons, listboxes, datagridviews etc of Control A around  from the designer of Control B. All it seems to let me do is resize the entirety of Control A.

Does anyone know how to make these custom controls containing multiple controls in such a way that they support design time resizing/moving?

Thanks

Isaac

Comment: are you sure you are not referring to Winform User Controls...http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_user_controls.html#User%20controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in way to do this.  You would essentially have to implement event handlers in order to handle the resizing of individual components within your control.  One alternative for you is to expose the `Size` and `Location` properties of each individual component to the control's clients.  For example, within the Control class you could do something like this:

```
public Size Component1Size
{
     get { return component1.Size; }
     set { component1.Size = value; }
}

public Point Component1Location
{
    get { return component1.Location; }
    set { component1.Location = value; }
}
```

and do this for each component of your control.  I think this would be your best option, even though the user won't be able to physically click/drag the components to move and resize them.

Comment: Ok, it looks like this is my only option then. Thanks Alex.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can my friend ,you need to create a SizeAble and DragAndDrop pannel where you can Insert Controls and by Moving That Pannel you can reach that .And for the Resizing Issue you can play with Anchor of Control's that you already added .

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class SizeablePanel : Panel {
  private const int cGripSize = 20;
  private bool mDragging;
  private Point mDragPos;

  public SizeablePanel() {
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
    this.BackColor = Color.White;
  }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    ControlPaint.DrawSizeGrip(e.Graphics, this.BackColor,
      new Rectangle(this.ClientSize.Width - cGripSize, this.ClientSize.Height - cGripSize, cGripSize, cGripSize));
    base.OnPaint(e);
  }

  private bool IsOnGrip(Point pos) {
    return pos.X >= this.ClientSize.Width - cGripSize &&
           pos.Y >= this.ClientSize.Height - cGripSize;
  }

  protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
    mDragging = IsOnGrip(e.Location);
    mDragPos = e.Location;
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
  }

  protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e) {
    mDragging = false;
    base.OnMouseUp(e);
  }

  protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (mDragging) {
      this.Size = new Size(this.Width + e.X - mDragPos.X,
        this.Height + e.Y - mDragPos.Y);
      mDragPos = e.Location;
    }
    else if (IsOnGrip(e.Location)) this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;
    else this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    base.OnMouseMove(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting. So for example, if he's extending from UserControl and uses this panel as his main parent component, and then drops all his other components onto this panel, when he drops the UserControl onto another form he'll be able to resize the components individually within that instance of the UserControl? Just by looking at this code, it's hard for me to tell how that would work...

Comment: Yes it does ,you can add this Panel which Extends Panel and Panel Extends Control ,so you can put every WinForm Control on it ,than you can Resize ,and you can add if you want the Possibility of Drag and Drop in Mouse Move ,or you can add another Form in the Main form ,just you should in Child Form do Form.TopLevel = False .

Comment: When I have some time, I'll check this out.